# how can i email the contents of a shopping cart back to the web moderator

Tags: php, html-email, shopping-cart

instead of doing a traditional  shopping cart checkout because of what we sell we need the checkout button to email the cart back to the web moderator for him to give approval what I have now it grabs the product out of the database but when it sends the email it sends a separate email for every line item in the shopping cart I want one email with the entire shopping cart its most likely a looping issue but  can't seem to figure it out any help would be much appreciated`

```
foreach($_SESSION['shoppingCart'] as $key => $product)
        {
            if (isset($_POST['checkout']))
                {
            $result = $this->qry("SELECT * FROM product WHERE Item_num=?", array($product['ID']));
            foreach ($result as $row)
            {
                echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$product['Quantity'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$row['Price'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>$'.number_format($product['Quantity'] * $row['Price'], 2).'</td>';
                    echo '<td><form method="POST">
                        <button type="submit" name="removeFromCart" value="'.$product['ID'].'">
                        Remove</button></form></td>';
                echo '</tr>';
                $total = $total + ($product['Quantity'] * $row['Price']);
                $price= $row['Price'];
                $lprice= $product['Quantity'] * $row['Price'];
                $quan= $product['Quantity'];
                    $name = $row['Name'];
                    $quantity = $product['Quantity'];

                    $to = 'ms245@zips.uakron.edu';
                    $subject = 'order from fatfish aquatic website';





                        $message = "<html><body>";
                        $message .= "<table>";
                        $message .= "<th>Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th> <th> line total</th>";

                        $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$quan.'</td><td>'.$price.'</td><td>'.$lprice.'</td></tr>";

                        $message .="123";
                    $message .= "</table>";
                    $message .= $total;
                    $message .= $row['Name'];
                    $message .= 'shipping address <br>';
                    $message .= 'phone number <br>';


                }
                $message .= 'email<br>';
                        $message .= "</body></html>";
                        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= "From: ms245@zips.uakron.edu\r\n"."X-Mailer: php";

                            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);





                }

            }`
```

Comment: Your `mail()` function is inside the loop...

Comment: @mitchell-secaur I have provided an answer for you, please consider marking as the accepted answer if you feel this solves your issue, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, I have refactored the code so that your `mail` call is made after you have looped through your cart and assembled the line item details. I am not clear why you would echo the "remove product" forms at this juncture in your code - if you are making and sending the final email of the order details, the order must already have been placed, right? You will need to rethink this aspect of it, however I have demonstrated how you can refactor your email message building code to get what you have asked for.

```
if (!empty($_POST['checkout'])) {

    // initialise message
    $message = "<html><body>";
    $message .= "<table>";
    $message .= "<th>Name</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th><th>line total</th>";

    foreach ($_SESSION['shoppingCart'] as $key => $product) {
        $result = $this->qry("SELECT * FROM product WHERE Item_num = ?", array($product['ID']));
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            // line item details added to message
            $name = $row['Name'];
            $quantity = $product['Quantity'];
            $price = $row['Price'];
            $lprice = $quantity * $price;
            $total += $lprice;
            $totalFormatted = number_format($total, 2);
            $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td>'.$name.'</td><td>'.$quantity.'</td><td>'.$price.'</td><td>'.$lprice.'</td></tr>";
            $message .= "123";
            $message .= $name;
        }
    }

    // finalise message
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "<p id='checkout-summary'>";
    $message .= "total: &#36;{$totalFormatted} <br>";
    $message .= 'shipping address <br>';
    $message .= 'phone number <br>';
    $message .= 'email<br>';
    $message .= "</p>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";

    $to = 'ms245@zips.uakron.edu';
    $subject = 'order from fatfish aquatic website';
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ms245@zips.uakron.edu\r\n" . "X-Mailer: php";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
```

Comment: The table heading, row and table gets repeated in the body for each line item in your code and the shipping address, phone and email sits outside the table in the body?

Comment: @Syfer The table heading should not have been there, true, oversight on my part. However, of course we want a new `<tr>` for each line item? As for the straggling summary info in the body, that's as per his source code, not for me to decide on that although I have wrapped in a `<p>`. This is SO, not a code writing service, I was simply _illustrating_ how he _could_ refactor to address his actual question of "it sends a separate email for every line item in the shopping cart - I want one email with the entire shopping cart"

Comment: I understand but you can point out error (don't fix just point out) that this is now it might look.

Comment: I did - see top of my post _"I have demonstrated how you can refactor your email message building code to get what you have asked for"_ This does not claim to be a fix. You cannot "fix" a question like this - just take a look at the source code!